# CK Editor not showing in development in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

I have included every files in my application but my CKeditor is not showing in development while showing in production in rails.

Comment: Hi better read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.